# ¿Qué es más eficiente punteros o variables?

Tags: c++, arduino

Que es mas eficiente en memoria y tiempo de reloj, usar en una función  con una variable puntero o una variable normal, dejo un ejemplo para que se pueda entender mejor:

```
int main(){          |   int main(){
    int x = 5;       |       int x = 5;
    f1( &x );        |       f2( x );
    return 0;        |       return 0;
}                    |   }
                     |
void f1( int *x ){   |   void f2( int x ){
    *x = *x + 4;     |       x = x + 4;
     cout << *x ;    |       cout<< x ; 
}                    |   }
```

El primer ejemplo es usando un puntero que apunta a 'x' y la otra es asignando 'x' a la función, necesito saber cual es mas optimo en tiempo de reloj y memoria para mi seguidor de linea en arduino, ya que en el ejemplo la verdad no importa mucho pero en arduino el proceso se va a repetir muchas veces por minuto y lo mejor es optimizarlo lo mas posible. Gracias de antemano <3 .

Answer (score 8):

> ¿Qué es más eficiente punteros o variables?

Ni lo uno ni lo otro. Un programa no es más o menos eficiente por usar un tipo de datos u otro, lo es por hacer lo mismo con menos cálculos.

---

Tus ejemplos no son equivalentes, en el de la izquierda:

```
int main(){
    int x = 5;
    f1( &x );
    return 0;
}

void f1( int *x ){
    *x = *x + 4;
     cout << x ;
}
```

La variable `x` de `main` finalizará el programa con valor `9`. La función `f1` recibe una dirección de memoria (que podría ser un tipo de dato con tamaño mayor a `int`), modifica el valor al que dicha dirección apunta y muestra la dirección por consola.

El de la derecha:

```
int main(){
    int x = 5;
    f2( x );
    return 0;
}

void f2( int x ){
    x = x + 4;
    cout<< x ; 
}
```

La variable `x` de `main` finalizará el programa con valor `5`. La función `f1` recibe un valor entero (que será la copia del valor de `main`), suma un valor al recibido como argumento y muestra el valor por consola.

Así que ninguno de los dos códigos es más eficiente que el otro ¡ni siquiera hacen lo mismo!.

#### El [principio de Pareto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_Pareto) (O la regla del 80/20) y la [Optimización Prematura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura).

La mayoría del código redactado se ejecuta poco, en general se estima que el 80% del código se usa un 20% o menos, por este motivo se considera mala práctica preocuparse por el rendimiento de un código específico sin conocer de antemano cuán crítico es ese código para con el programa. Si de verdad te preocupa la optimización no te centres en trivialidades sobre punteros o variables: busca las partes críticas de tu aplicación, realiza [medidas de rendimiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(inform%C3%A1tica)) y si realmente el rendimiento es inaceptable busca entonces (no antes) maneras de mejorarlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, los códigos no hacían lo mismo porque me equivoque al no poner el `*` en el primer `cout<<x`, me disculpo por eso. Aunque el código del seguidor esta listo y me e esforzado en optimizar mas el algoritmo que las trivialidades, Me entro la duda de igual manera y quería saber la conclusión ¿ Son lo mismo o tienen alguna diferencia ?, ya que supongo la respuesta fue al código que redacte mal. Lo siento si algo reiterativo.

Comment: Aunque se te haya olvidado des-referenciar el puntero en el `std::cout` de `f1` ambos códigos siguen sin hacer lo mismo. La respuesta sigue siendo la misma: No es más o menos eficiente por usar un tipo u otro de datos si no por hacer lo mismo con menos cálculos.